# how to make mysql structure of up,down rating

Tags: sql, mysql

Every programmer here knows about ratings like that:
[Rating system http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/4241/98948761.gif](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/4241/98948761.gif)

The problem is that I don't know how to make my SQL structure for that.

I think I can add up and down field in `article` table in MySQL, but this does not allow multi voting.

Could you please tell me how to make it?
Do I have to create a new table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply store the vote counter per article.
When an article gets voted up, increase the counter. Voting down - decrease the counter.

If you need to keep track about which user voted up/down (and avoid multiple votes), you need to define an intersection table between `users` and `articles`.

It could look like this:

```
article_votes
--------------
user_id
article_id
vote
```

where vote can be either +1 or -1.

If you need the points of an article, you get it by

```
SELECT SUM( vote )
FROM article_votes
WHERE article_id = <your_article_id>
```

Comment: thats is he same i think and this is the first time know the sum()

Answer (score 2):

You may get some ideas out of how stackoverflow does it:

- [Stack Overflow Creative Commons Data Dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/)
- [Understanding the StackOverflow Database Schema](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Understanding_the_StackOverflow_Database_Schema)
- [Meta Stackoverflow: Anatomy of a data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump/2678#2678)